# Azure bot services bug? 404 when canceling oauth for slack

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I want to handle a scenario when a user cancels an oauth request (for slack in this case) that it redirects to my defined landing page with the passed parameters.

However, Azure now redirects to a 404 and doesn't forward my request.

When I click the "cancel" button in slack it goes to: https://slack.botframework.com/Home/auth?error=access_denied&state=mybot

Which seems expected behaviour. However rather than botframework handling this cancel state, I would like to at least show a message to my user that his request failed rather than showing him a 404 page.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: How are you currently handling the cancel state? Can you post the code?

Comment: Currently i'm not handling any specific for the slack cancel state. Reason for this is because it doesn't follow the redirect url on the cancel state.

Comment: Are you testing any specific sample from botbuilder [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples)? Also, could you post your code where the oauth part is implemented?